# Is this possible in mysql (input from keyboard)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query is sql where the number is from keyboard

SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Number >= [Please insert min value:];

Is this possible in MySql? how should i write it?

Comment: How are you running the query?

Comment: MySQL is not Access.  How are you running the query?

Comment: i use MySQL Workbench. And i want to know if this query (which is made in Access) can be translated to work in MySQL Workbench.(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You are probably using M$ Access as a desktop application.  MySQL doesn't do that.